# Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ and periodicity

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider that

$$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

and

$$(a+b)^k = \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i}a^ib^{k-i}.$$

Then:

$$\sin (x + 2\pi)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x+2\pi)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \\=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}\left({2n+1 \choose i}x^{2n+1-i}(2\pi)^{i}\right)\right] =\\=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}\left({2n+1 \choose i}x^{-i}(2\pi)^{i}\right)\right].$$

Since $\sin(x) = \sin(x+2\pi)$, then I can conclude that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}{2n+1 \choose i}x^{-i}(2\pi)^{i} = 1 ~\forall x, n$$

Obviously, this is wrong. But I can't figure out where is the error.

Comment: You can't conclude that your sum is 1, because you are not allowed to change order in an infinite series.

Comment: @user4419802 I don't think this is the problem, since he is working with normally convergent series.

Comment: @Crostul $\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}(...)$ is not converging. It's not possible to move it outside first sum.

Comment: @user4419802 how can you say that a finite sum is not converging?

Comment: @Crostul Ouch, I said something wrong. The argument is that the uniqueness of coefficients holds for Taylor series but the expression is not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two normally convergent series and suppose you have that they are equal ina  neighborhood of $0$, i.e.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} b_n x^n$$

then you can conclude that for all $n$ you have $a_n=b_n$.

In your case you used
$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}, \qquad b_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{i} x^{-i}(2 \pi)^i$$

and you conclude that $1=\frac{b_n}{a_n} = \sum_{i=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{i} x^{-i}(2 \pi)^i$.

However you applied this criterion wrongly, since the coefficient $\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{i} x^{-i}(2 \pi)^i$ depends on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your last double sum is not a product of sums but a nested double sum. This becomes apparent from the fact that the values of the "inner" sum depend on the outer summation variable $n$.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you. Anyway, I have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}{{2n+1} \choose i}x^{-i}(2\pi)^{i}\right)\right]$$. So for any given $n$, the inner parenthesis has a value.